# html and css table overlap border with tr and td

Tags: html, css

I have a table that has a border and I want to keep the table scrollable.

The rows in the table have a bottom border. What I want is to have the two overlap border but don't cause the scroll bar to appear unless a another row is added.

Making the last `<td>` not have a border won't work because the rows are dynamic they can be added or deleted.

Something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/7zupuvc4/2/), but not have the scrollbar appear unless there's another row.

I want it to look [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/7zupuvc4/6/), but when theres a new row, it'll scroll but adding a overflow:scroll to table, creates the scrollbar when there are no new rows.

```
<div class="table-wrapper" style="height:272px;border: solid 1px #CCC;">
<table>
<tbody>
 <tr>
 <td>
     stackoverflow 
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
     stackoverflow 
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
     stackoverflow 
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
     stackoverflow 
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
     stackoverflow 
 </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

tbody{
  width:100%;
}
td{
  height:50px;
  border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC;
  width:100%;
}
tr{
  width:100%;
}
.table-wrapper{
  overflow:auto;
}
table{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: You can remove the padding on the table cells or set the box-sizing to border-box.

Comment: I want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/7zupuvc4/6/ but when theres another row added, the table can scroll, right now its set to hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this :

```css
.table-wrapper {
    overflow : hidden;
    height : 300px;
}

.table-wrapper, table {
    height : 300px;
}

.table-wrapper, td {
    border : solid 1px #CCC;
}

table, tbody, tr, td {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}

table {
    margin: 1px 0 0 0;
    overflow : auto;
}

td {
    height: 60px;
    border-width : 0 0 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
        <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td>stackoverflow</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>stackoverflow</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>stackoverflow</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>stackoverflow</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>stackoverflow</td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mt3uvq5r/18/))

Comment: what I want is that the two borders of the table and row to overlap such that it won't create a scroll bar so it looks like https://jsfiddle.net/7zupuvc4/6/.  but when I add another row, there should be a scroll bar

Comment: @LunZhang : Could you [**try my Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mt3uvq5r/5/) and let me know what is missing (if anything)?!

Comment: the last row is bigger than the other rows.  I want the rows to fit perfectly into the table such that the border of the last row and table overlap without the table creating a scroll bar but at the same time, if a new row is added a scroll bar would appear.

Comment: @LunZhang : What about now? [**Is this what you're looking for?**](https://jsfiddle.net/mt3uvq5r/6/)

Comment: @ John Slegers no :( lets say I have a table with defined height 300px, and I want 5 rows to fit perfectly into the table such that the border of the last row and table overlap without creating a scrollbar, there'll only be one border.  but when I remove a row, all 4 rows will still have a border bottom and if I add a row there'll be a scrollbar.

Comment: well if you remove a row, the last row won't have a border-bottom now

Comment: @LunZhang : I updated my code yet again. [**Could you try my last version?**](https://jsfiddle.net/mt3uvq5r/13/)

Comment: thanks I guess this work around will work!  I had this https://jsfiddle.net/7zupuvc4/12/ but if you zoom in and out it messes up, so I'll use ur approach.

Comment: @LunZhang : I made a few more improvements. [**Here's the final version**](https://jsfiddle.net/mt3uvq5r/15/).

Comment: whats wrong with the prev version?  it looks more straight forward for me

Comment: @LunZhang : The final version has better browser support. Also, the previous version had a double border (2px) for row 5 when you had more than 5 items and you didn't scroll. In the final version, this has been fixed as well.

Answer (score 0):

NEW ANSWER AFTER READING COMMENT and rereading question (I am still not sure what you exactly want, but I am guessing).

Have you tried this:

```
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: This won't work because if i remove rows, the last one won't have a border. exe. when theres only one row.  height of wrapper doesn't change

Comment: I'm sorry if the questions unclear but I want something like this jsfiddle.net/7zupuvc4/6 but when theres more rows it'll scroll

Comment: what I want is to have a certain amount of rows fit perfectly into the table such that the bottom border of the last row and table wrapper overlap and doesn't create a scroll option. but when you add an extra row, a scroll bar will appear

Comment: well, combine the two solutions I proposed: `border-collapse: collapse;` for the table, and a fixed height (265px), `overflow-y: auto` and `border-bottom: none` for the table-wrapper. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/yssbu3ak/

Comment: something like the link you showed me but if you remove some rows to 3 rows, the table won't have a border-bottom

Comment: another version: https://jsfiddle.net/hfqwfogg/1/ leaves the bottom border for the wrapper but takes it off the last td

Comment: same thing if I remove some rows, the last row won't have a border bottom

Answer (score 0):

Make the td of height:50px for example and the table of height 100px;

modify the first line in the editor in this link :
https://jsfiddle.net/7zupuvc4/2/
 to this :

```
<div class="table-wrapper" style="height:100px;border: solid 1px #CCC;">
```

the whole answer is :

```
<div class="table-wrapper" style="height:100px;border: solid 1px #CCC;">
<table>
<tbody>
 <tr>
 <td>
     stackoverflow 
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
     stackoverflow 
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
     stackoverflow 
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
     stackoverflow 
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
     stackoverflow 
 </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
tbody{
  width:100%;
}
td{
  height:50px;
  border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC;
  width:100%;
}
tr{
  width:100%;
}
.table-wrapper{
  overflow:auto;
}
table{
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a few things you can do:

> reset border-spacing (and also height of div to see full rows )
>
> select either  **last tbody/tfoot** and **then last tr** to erase border-bottom on the **very last row** (cause still a bit will show somehow :) ).

https://jsfiddle.net/7zupuvc4/7/

```css
tbody {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
  width: 100%;
}
:last-of-type tr:last-of-type td {
  /* here select either the last tbody or tfoot and then last tr ... */
  border-bottom: 0 solid;
}
tr {
  width: 100%;
}
.table-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 2px 0;/* div height is reset too */
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper" style="height:264px;border: solid 1px #CCC;">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            stackoverflow
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td>
            stackoverflow
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            stackoverflow
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            stackoverflow
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            stackoverflow
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

or maybe a max-height is what you looked for ?  https://jsfiddle.net/7zupuvc4/10/

```css
table:hover tbody + tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
tbody + tbody {
  display: none;
}
tbody {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
  width: 100%;
}
table >:last-of-type tr:last-of-type td {
  /* here select either the last tbody or tfoot and then last tr ... */
  border-bottom: 0 solid;
}
tr {
  width: 100%;
}
.table-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 2px 0;
  /* div height is reset too */
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper" style="max-height:264px;border: solid 1px #CCC;">
  <table>
    <tbody>

      <tr>

        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>

      <tr>

        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Update after comments using FLEX boxmodel :

```css
table , tbody {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

tbody {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

tr {
  min-height: 54px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
}

.table-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}

td {/* you wish to set td content in middle ? */
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

/* demo purpose */
.show, .show~tr {
  display:none;
  }
table:hover tr {
  display:flex;
  }

table >:last-of-type tr:last-of-type td {
  /* here select either the last tbody or tfoot and then last tr ... */
  border-bottom: 0 solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper" style="height:272px;border: solid 1px #CCC;">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
      
      
      <tr class="show">
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          stackoverflow
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: setting last tr to erase bottom won't work https://jsfiddle.net/7zupuvc4/9/  the last row doesn't have a border bottom now

Comment: @LunZhang , okay, so what is really the epected behavior ? beside, do you realize that , visitor may have another font-size or font-family set because font is not avalaible on his system or that he zooms the text to be able to read it . or maybe you look for max-height ?  it will scrll as soon as it reaches the max-height https://jsfiddle.net/7zupuvc4/10/

Comment: every row should have a border-bottom and the table has a defined height.  I want the two borders of the table and row  to overlap on the bottom without the scrollbar to appear, but not get rid of the scroll bar completely so that when another rows added a scroll bar will appear

Comment: @LunZhang the scroll bar does appear when needed , test the second  snippet i put in my answer (over the table to show more rows and scrollbar )

Comment: this won't work because I want a definite height for the table wrapper and when there less rows, the last row won't have a border.  https://jsfiddle.net/mt3uvq5r/

Comment: @LunZhang then you need javascript to resize height of your rows, or use flex; https://jsfiddle.net/7zupuvc4/11/

Comment: what you showed me, the two borders are still not overlapping, this makes the bottom border look darker, and the height can't change, the table will scroll when there are more rows

Comment: @LunZhang so this is why the last border needs to be hidden ... wrapper as a bottom border aready, doesn't it ?, if you want to hide it 2px lower, then scrollbars appears :) ... hope you find your way.

Comment: yes wrapper has a bottom border, when there are enough rows to reach the bottom of the border, the last rows border should become one with the wrappers border without creating a scroll

Comment: @LunZhang i wrote earlier in my answer : _**select either last tbody/tfoot and then last tr to erase border-bottom on the very last row (cause still a bit will show somehow :) ).**_  I'm stopping here, i think with these many answers and comments, you should have plenty info to finalise and eventually look for a compromise :)

Comment: thank you for your help but if I do that, when theres only one row, that row won't have a border bottom

Comment: thanks for your help but John Slegers had what I wanted.

Comment: @LunZhang !? https://jsfiddle.net/mt3uvq5r/19/  https://jsfiddle.net/mt3uvq5r/20/ what did you comment about then ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by adding border for the table and seprately for the `<th>` & `<td>`

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

td:not(:last-child),
th:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

td {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```